# PHP: AND operator not working in mysql

Tags: php

I am beginner in php. I am using core PHP.  I want to make onkeyup filter in input box.I used some ajax for display the data in same page and i am trying these php code.

```
$text = $_POST['text'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from project where name LIKE '%$text%' or type LIKE '%$text%' or sector LIKE '%$text%' or city LIKE '%$text%' or builder LIKE '%$text%' && status='1' LIMIT 6");
```

**My filter is working but not comparing with status status=1. status=0 is deleted item and status=1 is active item. But in my filter box status=0 is also showing.**

Please solve the problem. Your answer is highly appreciated.
Thanks

**EDIT: I tried both &&, AND operator. Still not working**

Comment: use `AND` in MySQL, not `&&`

Comment: use AND instead of &&

Comment: Thanks for the answer. AND also not working

Comment: Why don't `mysqli` tag?

Comment: you should also group the `AND`s and `OR`s with parenthesis `()`, if not, the `OR`s would make the result unpredictable

Comment: Also, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements, rather than concatenating variables into your query. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have problem with `syntax` of `mysql`. Use ``` (``) ``` in the field of tables.

You should use parenthesis wit `()` to group between `OR` and `AND`.
This may help.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from project where ((`name` LIKE '%$text%') OR (`type` LIKE '%$text%') OR (`sector` LIKE '%$text%') OR (`city` LIKE '%$text%') OR (`builder` LIKE '%$text%')) AND `status`='1' LIMIT 6");
```